# How can I handle Axios erros with RTK?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I have service which send request to server by axios.

```
async login(query: LoginQuery) {
    return await axios
      .get<UserModel>(`${this._apiPath}${API_PATH.AUTH}${AUTH_API.LOGIN}`, {
        params: query,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      })
      .then(userData => userData.data)
      .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response) {
          throw new Error(error.response.data)
        }
      })
  }

export type UserModel = {
  token: string,
  name: string,
  email: string
}
```

this function return union type `Promise<void | UserModel>`

And here I have my RTK func:

```
export type ServerError = {statusCode: number, message: string, error: string}
export const login = createAsyncThunk<
  UserModel,
  LoginQuery,
  {
    rejectWithValue: ServerError
    extra: { service: { Auth: AuthService } }
  }
>(
  AuthActionType.LOGIN,
  async (userData: LoginQuery, { rejectWithValue, extra: { service: { Auth } } }) => {
    return await Auth.login(userData)
      .then(userResponse => userResponse)
      .catch((error: ServerError) => rejectWithValue(error))
  }
)
```

Here I have error which say that Type 'void | UserModel | RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'UserModel'.
How can I handle error from axios with correct typecast for RTK usage?

Try to use throw different error types.

Comment: For some scenarios there really isn't a way around type assertions (just doing `x as TheTypeIAssertItToBe`).

Comment: @timotgl for sure essential problem in this case that `axiox.get` returns  void | UserModel. Is any way to fix this?

Comment: The answer to this case is to throw here after if-statement block other error
``` async login(query: LoginQuery) {
    return await axios
      .get<UserModel>(`${this._apiPath}${API_PATH.AUTH}${AUTH_API.LOGIN}`, {
        params: query,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      })
      .then(userData => userData.data)
      .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response) {
          throw new Error(error.response.data)
        }
       throw new Error(error?.message)
      })
  }```
Also do not use await with then)